# Trying SteamVR w/ SteamVR-OpenHMD on Ubuntu 20.04: subproject openhmd broken

Tags: usb, steam

I try to get my Oculus Quest working with Ubuntu 20.04.

I ran into this issue:

`/home/leder/Git/SteamVR-OpenHMD/build/subprojects/openhmd/examples/simple/simple`

does not print Headset positions! Every position output is zero or one...

I compiled `subprojects/openhmd` by:

```
mkdir build 
cd build 
cmake .. -DOPENHMD_DRIVER_OCULUS_RIFT_S=ON
make 
sudo make install
```

`lsusb` detects the Quest as an USB 3.0 device.

How to get usable results from `openhmd`?

Best regards
Gerrit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though Quest support is in the works by OpenHMD, it is not supported currently (as you can see on [the device support list](http://www.openhmd.net/index.php/devices/))
Best is to keep updated on the socials and keep an eye out on the commit logs.

Comment: OK: I'll accept this as an answer! Confusing is: in steam shop when Headset "Oculus Rift" is supported then the games run on the quest, too! Perhaps you can shed a light on Rift being supported by openhmd?